# Problemas con OVERLAY de OGRE

Tags: c++, menú, interfaz-gráfica, ogre

Tengo problemas para hacer uso de los overlays de OGRE:

**playState.h**:

```
 #include <OgreOverlaySystem.h>
    #include <OgreOverlayElement.h>
    #include <OgreOverlayManager.h>
    #include <OgreFontManager.h>
    #include <OgreTextAreaOverlayElement.h>

    using namespace Ogre;

    Ogre::OverlayManager* _overlayManager;
    void createOverlay(); //Definicion de la funcion
```

**playState.cpp**

```
void PlayState::createOverlay() {
      Overlay *pMyOverlayLogo = (Overlay*) OverlayManager::getSingleton().getByName("Info");
      pMyOverlayLogo->show();
}
```

No entiendo porque explota cuando hago la ultima linea:

```
pMyOverlayLogo->show();
```

Podrían mostrarme un ejemplo del uso de Overlay?

Comment: aclara que no se de Ogre, pero primero podria poner el error que le da cuando dice "explota" quizas eso ayude a alguien a encontrar el error.Saludos

Comment: No hay error, simplemente dice "RUN FINESHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time ......."